# Looking for good algorithm for equal distribution

Tags: algorithm

i am working on an application in which a lot of newspaper clippings should be "thrown" randomly on y table.
however if using true random there is always the possibility that all clipings appear on one place. 
the client would prefer a more "equal" random distribution.

one of my solutions was:
if i have 20 clippings, calculate a grid with 20 fields and then put each clipping in a field with random x/y positions within that field.

anyone have a better / more clever solution?

thanks a lot!

Comment: That's a good, quick way of doing it.

Comment: i agree, but just remember you need a uniform distribution within each field, otherwise you will get "a grid of piles".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is known as a quasi-random sequence (or a low-discrepancy sequence). There are several well-known sequences like that, here's the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructions_of_low-discrepancy_sequences). Depending on your language of choice, ready-to-use libraries might be available (a couple of examples are mentioned in this question: [Recommendations for Low Discrepancy (e.g. Sobol) quasi-random sequences in Python/SciPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412339/recommendations-for-low-discrepancy-e-g-sobol-quasi-random-sequences-in-pytho)).

Comment: Ok, Thanks Will look into that, looks very perfect. Also now i know how it is called.

Answer (score 1):

Here what i would do....

As it is about clippings i suppose that the visual part is also important...

I would divide the table in 4 parts (equal in surface) and and one more (overlapping) part that represents the centre of the table. you can always play with the number of 4 and make it 6 or 8 but i would not go as high as 20.

Now you divide the clippings at random  x/y positions over the 5 parts.

Like this you will always have a "strong" centre of your table, but you guarantee that not all clippings are on one pile.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way of solving this problem is to flatten it to a linear object.  A grid of 4 x 5 can become a list of 20.  Just give each 'slot' a number (0 - 19) and use the following algorithm.  Hope you don't mind Java.

```
private void randomSlotFiller(int numberOfSlots) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSlots; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    while(!list.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print(list.remove(random.nextInt(list.size())) + " ");
    }
}
```

The algorithm works in the following way:

1. Create an empty list
2. Fill the list with our slot numbers
3. Randomly select and remove a slot until none remain.

Obviously just printing out the numbers are not going to do much good so modify the code as needed.

An example output might be:

```
15 9 17 13 8 10 6 11 3 7 2 19 4 0 12 18 16 5 1 14
```

Note: This algorithm provides even distribution across all 'slots' over many iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple brute-force approach:

- Keep a list of the points you have already picked.
- pick n random points
- Select among them the point that has the greatest minimal distance to all points on your list, throw away the others
- add that point to the list of points you have picked
- repeat until you have enough points

Basically, you always try out multiple points, and choose only the one that is furthest from all previously chosen points.

The runtime is O(n²)