# Generating low discrepancy quasi-random sequences in python/numpy/scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, random, numbers, scipy

There is [already a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412339/recommendations-for-low-discrepancy-e-g-sobol-quasi-random-sequences-in-pytho) on this but the answer contains a broken link, and being over two years old, I'm hoping there's a better solution now :)

Low discrepancy quasi-random sequences, e.g. Sobol sequences, fill a space more uniformly than uniformly random sequences. Is there a good/easy way to generate them in python?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the best alternative for Low Discrepancy sequences in Python is Sensitivity Analysis Library (SALib):

https://github.com/SALib/SALib

I think this is an active project and you can contact the author to check if the functionalities you need are already implemented. If that doesn't solve your problem, Corrado Chisari ported a SOBOL version made in Matlab (by John Burkardt) to Python, you can access it here:

http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/py_src/sobol/sobol.html

Someone cleaned up the comments in these sources and put them in the format of docstrings. It's much more readable and you can access it here:

https://github.com/naught101/sobol_seq

Comment: sobol-seq package that you have listed caps dimensions at 40. Are you aware of any package implemented that allows to generate higher dimension sobol numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Scipy has this option now http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.qmc.Sobol.html

PyTorch also proves option of generating sobol random numbers. It allows upto a dimension of ~1k and has an option to switch on scrambling.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.quasirandom.SobolEngine.html

Comment: scipy.stats.qmc does not seem to be available in the latest scipy distribution (1.6.2 at the time of this writing)

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do it now (as of SciPy version >= 1.7.1) is how I'm doing it here.  It's good for up to 21,201 dimensions as they implemented the Joe and Kuo algorithm, which is the highest number of dimensions you can get (opensource). [https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~fkuo/sobol/](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/%7Efkuo/sobol/)

Here I show how to use the base2 method (with Owen Scrambling) and the random method (which generates an arbitrary number of points from the sequence), and how to skip the first point.

Note that this routine can be quite slow (due to the ndtri, or inverse normal distribution conversion of the points to shocks), especially in high dimensions + high simulation counts.  Point generation from the Sobol sequence itself is quite fast, but for most Monte Carlo simulations, you convert them into shocks (you may be using another distribution other than the standard normal).
This at least lets you generate the points in Python code directly.

Also, in the QMCgenerate routine, I'm skipping the first point (which is 0s) - while this is commonly done, some papers suggest not doing so (but I haven't seen a good alternative, if you have one, feel free to comment).  I transpose them just so I can paste them in Excel later and examine the generated shocks.  Anyway, hope those of you who need this algorithm find it useful.

```
from scipy.stats import qmc # needs SciPy >= 1.7.1
from scipy.special import ndtri
import numpy as np
import timeit

time_periods = 252
factors = 12

# IF using base2 generation, need a pow(2,m)
sims = 8192 

dimensions = factors*time_periods

def RQMCgenerate (dimensions, sims, seed):
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    m=10 # start at 1024 sims
    while pow(2,m) < sims: #m = 17 # 131,072 sims; M = 16 # 65,536 sims
        m = m+1
    RQMCgenerator = qmc.Sobol(dimensions, scramble=True, seed=seed)
    RQMCsamples = RQMCgenerator.random_base2(m)
    print('\n' + 'Time after sample generation RQMC:', (timeit.default_timer() - start_time), 'seconds'); 
    sobol = ndtri(RQMCsamples).T # get normsinv(points) and transpose to dimensions * sims 
    del RQMCsamples
    print('\n' + 'Time after ndtri (normsinv) of', sims,'sims x dimensions', dimensions, 'Randomized Sobol points): ', (timeit.default_timer() - start_time), 'seconds');
    return sobol

def QMCgenerate(dimensions, sims):
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    QMCgenerator = qmc.Sobol(dimensions, scramble=False)
    QMCgenerator.fast_forward(1) #skip first point where normsinv(0) = -Inf
    QMCsamples = QMCgenerator.random(sims) #this generates points not having to be powers of 2
    print('\n' + 'Time after sample generation QMC:', (timeit.default_timer() - start_time), 'seconds'); 
    sobol = ndtri(QMCsamples).T # get normsinv(points) and transpose to dimensions * sims
    del QMCsamples
    print('\n' + 'Time after ndtri (normsinv) of', sims,'sims x dimensions', dimensions, 'Sobol points):', (timeit.default_timer() - start_time), 'seconds');
    return sobol

RQMCsobol = RQMCgenerate(dimensions, sims, seed=0) #note sims changed with pow(2,m) if a power of 2 was not passed
sobol = QMCgenerate(dimensions, sims)
```

Time after sample generation RQMC:  0.4269224999952712  seconds

Time after ndtri (normsinv) of 8092 sims x dimensions 3024 Randomized Sobol points):  1.0048970999996527  seconds

Time after sample generation QMC:  0.0630135999963386  seconds

Time after ndtri (normsinv) of 8092 sims x dimensions 3024 Sobol points):  0.5444753999981913  seconds

This gets much slower at higher sims*dimensions, although I haven't found a faster conversion of points to normally distributed shocks than ndtri in Python:

Time after sample generation RQMC:  2.1779929000040283 seconds

Time after ndtri (normsinv) of 131072 sims x dimensions 3024 Randomized Sobol points): 10.617904700004146 seconds

Time after sample generation QMC:  1.079756200000702 seconds

Time after ndtri (normsinv) of 131072 sims x dimensions 3024 Sobol points): 9.545934699999634  seconds

Comment: SciPy's maintainer author of the QMC submodule here. Please do not skip the first point. We had extensive discussions with all the QMC community and there are only drawbacks to do it. Use scrambling if you don't want to have some 0s. Art Owen wrote a paper on this https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.08051

Comment: For sampling using another distribution than uniform, prefer using an inverse transform (see MultivariateNormalQMC for instance) or just use a sampling method we have that handles QMC rvs (soon in 1.9). http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.sampling.NumericalInverseHermite.html

Comment: @tupui I realize the research papers around QMC sequences have determined skipping the first point is not recommended; however, many in practice still skip it.  If you have enough simulations then it really doesn't matter, pragmatically speaking.

Comment: No it matters and that's exactly the point of the article. See the figures. With just a single point missing the properties are lost and the convergence rate is dramatically dropping. And there is no recovery with the number of points increasing. Sobol' is a power of 2 sequence and only performs as advertised under specific conditions. Otherwise you just have normal QMC rate of 1/n instead of 1/(3/2)

Comment: The article shows using a leap parameter and the resulting change in the distribution of the points generated.  Skipping one point in option pricing has virtually no impact, except according to academics.  The first point is 0 which means "no change" if you are pulling from an inverse normal distribution for example, or any inverse distribution.  If the number of points used is say 1024, the most error you'd have is weighted by 1/1024, ~0.000977.  I'm just referring to reality here, and not academic exercises in why something is mathematically incorrect, but fine in practice.

Comment: I know the option pricing case as I’ve been working on it with Sergei Kucherenko. And I can confirm that it still matters. (BTW that’s a simple case where you clearly see the issue). I also evaluated dozens of cases and noticed the convergence loss. By discarding the first point you are breaking the properties and balance of the net. 

If you scramble you would not have 0. What you could also do, which is valid, is skip 2^m and sample 2^n with n<m.

Comment: @tupui that is probably worthy of another stack exchange post to show the examples of how it affects option pricing or anything else for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

[Chaospy](https://github.com/jonathf/chaospy) is also a valid option. One can select several approaches for low-discrepancy sampling (including 'Sobol, latin hypercube, etc) - for more details see [the documentation](https://chaospy.readthedocs.io/en/master/sampling/index.html).