# How to perform a quasirandom shuffle on Python?

Tags: python, random

If I have an 2-d numpy array, how can I perform a quasirandom shuffle on it? What I would like to do is have as an input the numpy array, and then have it shuffled in the same way as random.shuffle() would do it, but instead of using pseudorandom approach, use quasirandom approach (for example sobol or halton).

It seems there are three parts to this:

1) generating quasirandom sequences (e.g. sobol)

2) mapping the sequence with the data

3) performing the shuffle based on that

Comment: what do you mean by quasi-random? do you want to be able to provide a seed to a prng so you can get consistent results? Are you shuffling along all axes or just a few? we need more information to answer your question. You should also include what you have tried and where you ran into trouble.

Comment: Thanks for helping to clarify the question :) I've edited the question in a way that seems to address your comment.

Comment: I found a question on [Generating sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433891/generating-low-discrepancy-quasi-random-sequences-in-python-numpy-scipy). Does this help?

Comment: I saw that, thanks. It's certainly part of the puzzle i.e. it seems that the best approach would be to generating quasirandom sequence and then using that to make the shuffle. But it seems that the library is definitely not built for the purpose I'm looking for nor directly facilitate for it, and there was no relevant documentation / examples available.