# How to generate high dimensional Gaussian vectors via quasi-mont carlo (QCM) techniques in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random, covariance

i would like to generate a set of gaussian vectors of mean m and covariance C in bumpy, the standard approach is

```
samplings_set = np.zeros((n,m.size))
for i in range(n):
    vect = np.random.multivariate_normal(m,C)
    vect.shape = (1,m.size)
    samplings_set[i,:] = vect
```

can i generate the ensemble via quasi-mont carlo (QCM) techniques in numpy? (in order to get a more representative samplings set)

Comment: does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788739/monte-carlo-simulations-in-python-using-quasi-random-standard-normal-numbers-usi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating random correlated x and y points using Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683821/generating-random-correlated-x-and-y-points-using-numpy)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Monte Carlo simulations in Python using quasi random standard normal numbers using sobol sequences gives erroneous values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55788739/monte-carlo-simulations-in-python-using-quasi-random-standard-normal-numbers-usi)